# How can I do this in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having this in my model.
However, the model is used as polymorphic and I want to have different condition.
How can I do code if I'm doing this in controller?

**models/comment.rb**

```
validates_length_of :body, 
                    :within => 10..100, 
                    :message => "must be between 10 to 100 characters"
```

UPDATE:

I only want to use this validation condition when  Community model is creating a comment into comment model.
Comment model is polymorphic!
It has commentable_type and commentable_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cann't do anything like this in controller. 
Use condition in your model or put this in community model.

```
validates_length_of :body, 
                    :within => 10..100, 
                    :message => "must be between 10 to 100 characters", :if => "community?"

  def community?
    return self.commentable_type == "Community"
  end
```

Comment: Can you do that if it polymorphic? More than 2 models are accessing to that model. But I want to validate only when the access is from community model.

Comment: As I mentioned, This model is polymorphic. I already have validation for regular case. But only one model has to have different condition. That's why I'm trying to do that in controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in the model

Answer (score 0):

In your model,

```
validates_length_of :body,
                    :when => [ :comment ],
                    :within => 10..100, 
                    :message => "must be between 10 to 100 characters"
```

and you could use `:unless` like ( `:unless => Community.new { |a| a.comment? }`)

This [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_length_of) would help you to understand and edit as per your needs. This is just an `idea` to solve your problems.